# Cannot read query params becouse vue.js is adding #/ to the end of url

Tags: vue.js, routes, url-parameters

I have a one page app in vueJS:

```
let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/',  component: Dis13HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', component: Dis13HomeComponent }
  ]
});
```

In main component in mounted() im getting the url param like this:

```
this.$route.query.token;
```

But if I open http://www.myapp.com/app.html?token=s56ds6d5d56f6ef6e it does not read the token parameter, becouse vue is adding `#/` to the end of url so it looks like http://www.myapp.com/app.html?token=s56ds6d5d56f6ef6e#/

If I open this format of url: http://www.myapp.com/app.html#/?token=s56ds6d5d56f6ef6e then it works, but this path is forbidden on server.

How could I read the token parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your router to work with `history` mode and you will not have the '#' anymore.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',     // <------------- HERE
  routes: [
    { path: '/',  component: Dis13HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', component: Dis13HomeComponent }
  ]
});
```